# In the logging module's RotatingFileHandler, how to set the backupCount to a practically infinite number

Tags: python

I'm writing a program which backs up a database using Python's [RotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html). This has two parameters, `maxBytes` and `backupCount`: the former is the maximum size of each log file, and the latter the maximum number of log files.

I would like to effectively never delete data, but still have each log file a certain size (say, 2 kB for the purpose of illustration). So I tried to set the `backupCount` parameter to `sys.maxint`:

```
import msgpack
import json
from faker import Faker
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import os, glob
import itertools
import sys

fake = Faker()
fake.seed(0)

data_file = "my_log.log"

logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = RotatingFileHandler(data_file, maxBytes=2000, backupCount=sys.maxint)
logger.addHandler(handler)

fake_dicts = [{'name': fake.name(), 'email': fake.email()} for _ in range(100)]

def dump(item, mode='json'):
    if mode == 'json':
        return json.dumps(item)
    elif mode == 'msgpack':
        return msgpack.packb(item)

mode = 'json'

# Generate the archive log
for item in fake_dicts:
    dump_string = dump(item, mode=mode)
    logger.debug(dump_string)
```

However, this leads to several `MemoryError`s which look like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 77, in emit
    self.doRollover()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 129, in doRollover
    for i in range(self.backupCount - 1, 0, -1):
MemoryError
Logged from file json_logger.py, line 37
```

It seems like making this parameter large causes the system to use lots of memory, which is not desirable. Is there any way around this trade-off?

Answer (score 5):

An improvement to the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53288524/3170631) suggested by [@Asiel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4557005/asiel-diaz-benitez)

Instead of using `itertools` and `os.path.exists` to determine what the `nextName` should be in `doRollOver`, the solution below simply remembers the number of last backup done and increments it to get the `nextName`.

```
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import os
class RollingFileHandler(RotatingFileHandler):

    def __init__(self, filename, mode='a', maxBytes=0, backupCount=0, encoding=None, delay=False):
        self.last_backup_cnt = 0
        super(RollingFileHandler, self).__init__(filename=filename,
                                                 mode=mode,
                                                 maxBytes=maxBytes,
                                                 backupCount=backupCount,
                                                 encoding=encoding,
                                                 delay=delay)

    # override
    def doRollover(self):
        if self.stream:
            self.stream.close()
            self.stream = None
        # my code starts here
        self.last_backup_cnt += 1
        nextName = "%s.%d" % (self.baseFilename, self.last_backup_cnt)
        self.rotate(self.baseFilename, nextName)
        # my code ends here
        if not self.delay:
            self.stream = self._open()
```

This class will still save your backups in an ascendant order (ex. first backup will end with ".1", the second one will end with ".2", and so on). Modifying this to do also do gzip is straight forward.

Comment: hello @SBK,  just a little detail: your solution will overwrite the backups every time the program run, so you need to save the last backup number persistently between program executions for this solution to work as expected

Comment: @AsielDiazBenitez, does your solution counter the problem of having to keep track of the existing number between the runs? i am trying to adapt this to kubernetes, where containers in each of multiple workers write to log-files in a PVC.

Comment: @NaveenReddyMarthala yes

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that `RotatingFileHandler` is intended to... well rotate, and actually if you set its `backupCount` to a big number the `RotatingFileHandler.doRollover` method will loop in a backward range from `backupCount-1` to zero trying to find the last created backup, the bigger the `backupCount` the slower it will be (when you have an small number of backups)

Also the `RotatingFileHandler` will keep renaming your backups which isn't necessary for what you want and actually it is an overhead, instead of simply putting your latest backup with the next ".n+1" extension it will rename all your backups and put the latest backup with the extension ".1" (will shift all backup names)

---

### Solution:

You could code the next class (probably with a better name):

```
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import itertools
import os
class RollingFileHandler(RotatingFileHandler):
    # override
    def doRollover(self):
        if self.stream:
            self.stream.close()
            self.stream = None
        # my code starts here
        for i in itertools.count(1):
            nextName = "%s.%d" % (self.baseFilename, i)
            if not os.path.exists(nextName):
                self.rotate(self.baseFilename, nextName)
                break
        # my code ends here
        if not self.delay:
            self.stream = self._open()
```

This class will save your backups in an ascendant order (ex. first backup will end with ".1", the second one will end with ".2", and so on)

Since `RollingFileHandler` extends `RotatingFileHandler` you can simply replace `RotatingFileHandler` for `RollingFileHandler` in your code, you don't need to provide the `backupCount` argument since it is ignored by this new class.

---

### Bonus solution: (compressing backups)

Since you will have an ever growing amount of log backups, you may want to compress them to save disk space. So you could create a class similar to `RollingFileHandler`:

```
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import gzip
import itertools
import os
import shutil
class RollingGzipFileHandler(RotatingFileHandler):
    # override
    def doRollover(self):
        if self.stream:
            self.stream.close()
            self.stream = None
        # my code starts here
        for i in itertools.count(1):
            nextName = "%s.%d.gz" % (self.baseFilename, i)
            if not os.path.exists(nextName):
                with open(self.baseFilename, 'rb') as original_log:
                    with gzip.open(nextName, 'wb') as gzipped_log:
                        shutil.copyfileobj(original_log, gzipped_log)
                os.remove(self.baseFilename)
                break
        # my code ends here
        if not self.delay:
            self.stream = self._open()
```

This class will save your compressed backups with extensions ".1.gz", ".2.gz", etc. Also there are other compression algorithms available in the standard library if you don't want to use `gzip`.

This is an old question, but hope this help.

Comment: In the above solution, if you don't like the fact that you're iterating from 1 upwards with `os.path.exists` to determine what the `nextName` should be then you can simply create a new class member to remember the last count of the backup file, increment it by 1 in `doRollOver` and use it to directly determine 'nextName'. Added an answer to this effect https://stackoverflow.com/a/57600255/3170631

Comment: @AsielDiazBenitez, I get  `AttributeError: type object 'RollingFileHandler' has no attribute 'split'` on python-3.8.12 on debian 11 while configuring the handler. how do i fix this? full traceback and `logging.config.dictConfig` here: https://pastebin.com/LAbS4x5x

Comment: @NaveenReddyMarthala looks like you are passing the class directly in that dict but the tool you are using is expecting an string, replace `"class": RollingFileHandler,` with `"class": "RollingFileHandler",`

Comment: `split` is from string, the lib you are using seems to expect an string like `"logging.Logger"`, you could try providing the full module path to the class `"your_package.RollingFileHandler"`, in any case that seems offtopic, the class provided in this answer does work and you can try to use it normally, if you are having issues related to other libs that use loggers you should create another question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try having a different base filename, every time like the following and have backupCount as 0.

```
import datetime
timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f")
data_file = "my_log_%s.log" % timestamp
```

Comment: As I understand it, if I set the `backupCount` to zero, rollover will never occur. However, I want rollover to occur whenever the log file exceeds `maxBytes`.

Comment: What would be the maximum data size, you get? If you can guess it, then you can have the backupCount.